# Unknown NMI reason 20 and 30 on a VM

Tags: linux, kvm, libvirt, nmi

I pulled up the console on a virtual machine I manage today and was greeted with some kernel messages:

```
[5912557.130943] Uhhuh. NMI received for unknown reason 20 on CPU 0.
[5912557.131115] Do you have a strange power saving mode enabled?
[5912557.131287] Dazed and confused, but trying to continue
[6064281.393568] Uhhuh. NMI received for unknown reason 30 on CPU 1.
[6064281.393888] Do you have a strange power saving mode enabled?
[6064281.394235] Dazed and confused, but trying to continue
```

That's just a few of them, both 20 and 30 occur on CPU 0 and 1.

- VM is Debian Jessie, BIOS boot ("QEMU Standard PC (i440FX + PIIX, 1996), BIOS 1.9.3-20161025_171302-gandalf 04/01/2014"; kernel 3.16.0-4-amd64)
- Hypervisor is libvirt/KVM running on Debian testing (currently Debian's 4.7.0-1-amd64; qemu 1:2.7+dfsg-3).
- Hardware is an Opteron 6344 on a [Supermicro H8SGL-F](http://www.supermicro.com/Aplus/motherboard/Opteron6000/SR56x0/H8SGL-F.cfm) with ECC RAM with scrub enabled.

I don't see any NMI or EDAC error/warning messages on the host.

Any idea what is causing these NMI messages on the guest? Are they anything to worry about?

(May be related to [NMI received for unknown reason 20 — Do you have a strange power saving mode enabled?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/216925/nmi-received-for-unknown-reason-20-do-you-have-a-strange-power-saving-mode-ena) but that appears to be bare metal).

Comment: I wonder wether it would help to pass to the kernel of the VMs `noapic apci=off`

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro Well, currently the VM is working without any (apparent) problems. It's in production, so I'd rather not go around rebooting to try random kernel options just to see. Would be a different story if it were to help a kernel dev to debug the problem, etc. (Plus, it's not like they're frequent—it'd take a while to be sure.)

Comment: I've been trying to track down the same issue for some time. Some data points that may be helpful are: host kernel version, qemu version, whether the VM uses BIOS or UEFI boot, whether the VM uses i440fx or q35.

Comment: @MichaelHampton requested details added to the question.

Comment: I've got the same issue, here are the details (very similar actually):
VM is Debian jessie (3.16.0-4-amd64) with BIOS 1.7.5-20140531_083030-gandalf (04/01/2014).
Hypervisor is libvirt/KVM on Debian jessie, but with backported kernel (4.7.0-0.bpo.1-amd64).
Hypervisor hardware is two Opteron 6272s, with ECC RAM (motherboard currently unknown, but likely Supermicro of some kind).
Given these details are remarkably similar to derobert's, I'm not too surprised that I encounter this issue too, but hopefully they help.

Comment: @MichaelHampton another person (jvperrin) has a similar setup and has posted details in the comment above this one. Pinging you because otherwise I doubt you'll be notified.

Comment: Well, this doesn't appear to be distro-specific, and [it's apparently almost three years old](https://lists.nongnu.org/archive/html/qemu-devel/2014-04/msg00395.html) with still no solution.

Comment: @MichaelHampton that is a bit different as no migration is involved here. Nor does it die after the error.

Comment: There doesn't have to be a migration for the problem to appear, as some of the list messages mentioned. And I wouldn't have brought it up if it were irrelevant.

Comment: Did you install the `qemu-guest-utils` package on the VM? It might be that the NMI (Non-Maskable Interrupt) is something qemu is trying to tell the guest OS. If that is the case, then the guest-utils package *should* take care of it.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue using a similar setup:

1. AMD CPU (although I've seen reports of the same issue with Intel CPUs, but none of my hypervisors running on Intel CPUs have this issue, even with CPU passthrough enabled).
2. Debian, kernel 4.x on the hypervisor and guest (4.9.0-4-amd64 in my case on both).

My solution was to switch my guest VM to use a QEMU emulated CPU rather than CPU passthrough. This entailed removing the `<cpu mode='host-passthrough'/>` line from the guest definition file.

**Update 1**:
I did further investigation and the troublesome elements were under the `clock` element:

```
<clock offset='utc'>
  <timer name='rtc' tickpolicy='catchup'/>
  <timer name='pit' tickpolicy='delay'/>
  <timer name='hpet' present='no'/>
</clock>
```

The real solution was to remove the three `<timer>` elements, after which `<cpu mode='host-passthrough'/>` could be enabled again.

For completeness I added [a similar answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/405949/5186) to the [linked question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/216925/nmi-received-for-unknown-reason-20-do-you-have-a-strange-power-saving-mode-ena).

**Update 2**
As Simon Richter [mentioned](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/522504/5186), this fix may not work for everyone as the settings I've removed are the defaults. If so, his solution should be followed.

Comment: These three elements are default values, disabling them should do precisely nothing and re-add them on save.

Answer (score 2):

The problem seems to be that the End of Interrupt isn't communicated properly.

For libvirt, make sure `eoi` is enabled:

```
<domain>
  …
  <features>
    <apic eoi='on'/>
    …
```

On the command line for KVM that translates to

```
-cpu …,+kvm_pv_eoi
```

This seems to work for us with `-M q35`, host cpu passthrough and default config otherwise (RTC interrupts queued, PIT interrupts dropped, HPET unavailable).

Answer (score 0):

`<acpi eoi="on"/>` does not work for me, after some time the problem re-occurs and `Uhhuh. NMI received for unknown reason 20 on CPU 0` are printed again by the Linux kernel.

During my further research I found two commits fixing bugs in the `iTCO_wdt` (Intel Total Cost of Ownership Watch-Dog Timer) Qemu emulation:

- [v2.9.0-rc0~56^2~1](https://gitlab.com/qemu-project/qemu/-/commit/6c608953a5512b556fd0913d740e932366d6bb5d)
- [v2.9.0-rc4~11^2](https://gitlab.com/qemu-project/qemu/-/commit/8c9f42f3cf3598e8bb612b3f81cd12632efd3ca4)

Debian-9-Stretch only had [qemu-2.8](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=qemu&searchon=sourcenames&suite=all&section=all), which does not contain those patches. Debian-10-Buster has qemu-3.1, where I did not observe the problem.

The driver can be added to the deny-list to prevent it from getting loaded:

```
echo blacklist iTCO_wdt >/etc/modprobe.d/itco-wdt.conf
```

After that make sure to shutdown and re-start the VM to kill the old Qemu process and get a new instance. A `reboot` re-uses the old Qemu process, which would preserves the broken state inside Qemu. But a `reboot` is required to trigger the bug as the bug never happend for me on 1st boot, but only after a reboot or a suspend-to-disk and resume cycle.

Answer (score -1):

I have had the same problem on `Debian 9` and `Qemu 2.8.1(Debian 1:2.8+dfsg-6+deb9u5)`.
I resolved it by replace videocard model from `virtio` to `cirrus` (or you can try use another model from `qemu` man page).

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem on Debian 11 hypervisor after cloning Debian 10, 11 VMs from another hypervisor.
It helped me to restart VMs and set CPU Model value `Clear CPU Configuration`.